# Encoding the theorem on friends and strangers in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> In every group chat of six (distinct) people on Instagram, there is a group of three (distinct) people such that either:
>
> - everyone in the group are friends
> - everyone in the group are strangers (i.e not friends).
>
> 1. Let $F(x,y)$ be a relation that denotes that $x$ and $y$ are friends on Instagram. Translate the statement into predicate logic.

So I believe this is using the pigeonhole principle.

> 2. Would the statement still be true if Instagram had only 3 users?

I have no idea where to start with the predicate logic.

Answer (score 1):

The first part doesn't ask you to *prove* anything. It just asks you to encode the [theorem on friends and strangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers) in predicate logic. Let's build this statement step by step. First, we want to go over all sets of six people: $$ \forall x_1 \cdots \forall x_6 $$ We are only interested in the case in which they are all distinct: $$ \bigwedge_{1 \leq i < j \leq 6} (x_i \neq x_j) \Rightarrow $$ There must be a set of three people which are either all friends or all strangers: $$ \bigvee_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 6} (F(x_i,x_j) \land F(x_j,x_k) \land F(x_k,x_i)) \lor (\lnot F(x_i,x_j) \land \lnot F(x_j,x_k) \land \lnot F(x_k,x_i)) $$
The second part asks whether the statement remains true if there are only three users. The statement is vacuously true, because then it is impossible to choose a set of six distinct users.

Answer (score 0):

Implication predicates A (x) and B (x)

A(x) ⇒ B(x)

is the union of the set T2 - the truth of the predicate B (x) and the complement to the set T1 of the truth of the predicate A (x).

Comment: How does this answer the question?